# AJAX - PHP update of multiple divs

Tags: php, ajax

Good morning everyone, i have this code, took from w3schools

```
var xmlhttp

function showCustomer(str,str2)
{
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
  return;
  }



var url="/Script/ajaxdb/aaaaa.php";
url=url+"?id="+str;
url=url+"&id2="+str2;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)  {



  document.getElementById("TXTHINT").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;





  }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return null;
}
```

I would like to change the name of the ID into

```
      document.getElementById("TXTHINT").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

I would like to have something like

```
  document.getElementById("TXTHINT1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

  document.getElementById("TXTHINT2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

  document.getElementById("TXTHINT3").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

and so on..

i tried

```
  document.getElementById("TXTHINT"+str).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

cause i need the value of the variable str, to have the id name as TXTHINT1, TXTHINT2, TXTHINT3 and so on....

but id doesn't work.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(str)` and see it's value?

Comment: no sorry, i am not so practice of javascript/ajax. is for debugging to see what's happen ?

Comment: the GoogleChrome JAvascript console, tell me Uncaught ReferenceError: str is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should specify a global var to access it in other functions.

```
var xmlhttp
var str_global;
function showCustomer(str,str2)
{
    str_global=str;
    xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp==null)
      {
      alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
      return;
      }



    var url="/Script/ajaxdb/aaaaa.php";
    url=url+"?id="+str;
    url=url+"&id2="+str2;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)  {

      document.getElementById("TXTHINT"+str_global).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i tried doing this but maybe i was doing it the wrong way. Now it works, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to set a class attribut for all elements you want to change.
For example:

```
<div id="TXTHINT" class="txthints"></div>
<div id="TXTHINT1" class="txthints"></div>
```

Now you could easily iterate through all elements with class atrribut "txthints" and set the content.

```
var divsToChange = document.getElementsByClassName('txthints');
var newContent = xmlhttp.responseText;

for(i=0; i < divsToChange.length; ++i ) {
 divsToChange[i].innerHTML = newContent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but instead of TXTHINT(1,2,3), I need TXTHINT(str value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function () {
>
> ```
>         stageChanged(str, str2);
>     };
> xmlHttp.open("GET", handlingURL, true);
> xmlHttp.send(null); }
> ```
>
> function stageChanged(str, str2) {
>
> ```
>     if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
>     {
>         document.getElementById("TXTHINT"+str).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
>         //do something with the response
>     } }
> ```

STR is not defined as a global parameter so it will not be able to accessible in the response function,  you need to pass str as a parameter.